# Getting error ValidationError: 1 validation error for Data data.products, when using Pydantic models

Tags: python, pydantic

Please, help me fix this error

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel): 
    id: int
    brand: str

class Products(BaseModel):
    products: list[Item]

class Data(BaseModel):
    data: dict[str, Products]

d = Data.model_validate({'data': {'products': [{'id': 1234, 'brand': 'infinix'}]}})
print(d)
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

> validation error for Data data.products
>
> Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of Products

Answer (score 1):

## First Solution

The Products need a `products` envelope in order to pass validation.

```py
d = Data.model_validate(
    {'data': 
      {'products':
        {'products': [{'id': 1234, 'brand': 'infinix'}]}
      }
    }
)
```

```
data={'products': Products(products=[Item(id=1234, brand='infinix')])}
```

---

## Second Solution

Modify the model definitions in order to use the original JSON.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    id: int
    brand: str

class Products(BaseModel):
    products: list[Item]

class Data(BaseModel):
    data: Products

d = Data.model_validate({'data': {'products': [{'id': 1234, 'brand': 'infinix'}]}})
print(d)
```

```
data=Products(products=[Item(id=1234, brand='infinix')])
```

Comment: But i am getting json data without this field

Comment: Then you have two options: 1. modify the JSON data to fit the models, 2. modify the models to fit the JSON data. I'll look into a solution which implements option 2.

Comment: @morism, added solution which works with the original JSON